# Do netty's UnPooled ByteBuf need Reference counted?

Tags: netty

Pooled ByteBuf need return to the pool when Reference count associated with it reach 0 according to http://netty.io/wiki/reference-counted-objects.html,But what do with ByteBuf alloc from UnPooled?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes there are reference counted to allow us free direct memory in a timely manner.

Comment: What about Unpooled heap buffers? If I know I allocated a heap buffer using Unpooled, is it legal to completely ignore reference counting in this case, i.e. not calling heapBuffer.release() or heapBuffer.retain()?